# Unset item in complex array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, `$args`:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ([term_id] => 3 [name] => Default [slug] => default [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 3 [taxonomy] => media_category [description] => The default media category. [parent] => 0 [count] => 0 [term_order] => 0 [category_count] => 0 [category_description] => The default media category. [cat_name] => Default [category_nicename] => default [category_parent] => 0 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 7 [name] => Animals [slug] => animals [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 7 [taxonomy] => media_category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [term_order] => 0 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Animals [category_nicename] => animals [category_parent] => 0 ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 8 [name] => Characters [slug] => characters [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 8 [taxonomy] => media_category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 1 [term_order] => 0 [category_count] => 1 [category_description] => [cat_name] => Characters [category_nicename] => characters [category_parent] => 0 ) 
)
```

When I try to remove the first item of the array...

```
unset($args[0]);
```

...nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: What do you expect to happen afterward? Did you `print_r($args)` after the `unset()`?  Array keys won't be changed, but 0 should be gone.

Comment: Ben, everybody doesn't have english as their first language. I believe the rating of the questions should reflect the quality and relevance of the question rather than the spelling. maybe you should head over to http://english.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
$first_arg = array_shift($args);
```

or if you want to remove an arbitrary element in an array:

```
array_splice($args,0,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unset.php) function will only delete a variable, it will not shrink your array.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.unset.php

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
foreach($args as $key=>$value){
$args[$key]=get_object_vars($value);
}
unset($args[0]);
```